# Execute a function when the entire page is displayed

Tags: plugins, functions

How can I execute a function, which is in a plugin, only once the entire page is displayed ?

Comment: Be more specific please and give the code for your function. Is it already hooked in WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last action you can do...

```
add_action('shutdown', 'before_the_end_of_world');

function before_the_end_of_world() {
   die('I will miss you, wordpress');
}
```